# Help identify vintage bike

Tags: vintage

I picked up this bike at a swap, and plan on restoring it.  However, I cannot find anything on the bike to identify what it may be (other than the design on the rear rack).  There is no serial number or any other identifying marks.  Does anyone have any idea what the make and model could be?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This style was common back in the 50s (and likely earlier).  Sears, J C Pennys, Tru-Value, Western Auto, et al, all sold house-brand bikes.  The one you have is in excellent condition!

Comment: It's a little hard to tell but the fork might be bent.

Comment: Thanks - there was once a sticker on the front, but it's gone.  I'm guessing it's not a Schwinn or other well-known name brand because there are no other identifiers.  I believe most bike manufacturers applied a more permanent identification somewhere on their bikes.  So - it remains a mystery.  It'll be fun restoring it though.